# Need help on ssh usage in a loop of shell script

Tags: bash

I need help on how to connect remote systems through ssh command in while loop of shell script. I was able to connect one remote system using ssh from shell script. Please find sample code snippet as given below…..

```
ssh "root@148.147.179.100" ARG1=$rpmFileName 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'        
  echo ">>Checksum ..."
  md5sum /root/$ARG1
ENDSSH
```

When tried to run same piece of code within a loop getting the error "syntax error: unexpected end of file", which I couldn’t resolve.

But when placing the same piece of code in another script file and using that file in while loop of another script, is working.

Can anyone help me with some solution.

---

Please find entire code as given below...

```
#!/bin/sh
rpmFileName=""
file="serverIps.txt"
dir="/home/rtulluri/downloads/EVAT-1123/AxisTar";
numberOfIps=0
axisTarfileTarget='/var'
#This function checks whether given ip is valid  or not
#returns 0 for valid ip, 1 for invalid ip
function valid_ip()
{
    local  ip=$1
    local  stat=1
    if [[ $ip =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]]
    then
        OIFS=$IFS
        IFS='.'
        ip=($ip)
        IFS=$OIFS
        [[ ${ip[0]} -le 255 && ${ip[1]} -le 255 \
            && ${ip[2]} -le 255 && ${ip[3]} -le 255 ]]
        stat=$?
    fi
    #echo "stat = $stat"
    return $stat
}
#Check whether given file exists or not
if [ -s $file ]
then
 echo "$file exists"
else
  echo "$file doesn't exist"
  echo "exiting ........"
  exit
fi
IFS=,
echo "---------------"
while read sysType serverIp uid pwd
do

  sysType="${sysType#"${sysType%%[![:space:]]*}"}"   # remove leading whitespace characters
  sysType="${sysType%"${sysType##*[![:space:]]}"}"   # remove trailing whitespace characters
  serverIp="${serverIp#"${serverIp%%[![:space:]]*}"}"   # remove leading whitespace characters
  serverIp="${serverIp%"${serverIp##*[![:space:]]}"}"   # remove trailing whitespace characters

  uid="${uid#"${uid%%[![:space:]]*}"}"   # remove leading whitespace characters
  uid="${uid%"${uid##*[![:space:]]}"}"   # remove trailing whitespace characters

  pwd="${pwd#"${pwd%%[![:space:]]*}"}"   # remove leading whitespace characters
  pwd="${pwd%"${pwd##*[![:space:]]}"}"   # remove trailing whitespace characters

  if [ -n "$serverIp" ]
  then
     valid_ip $serverIp
     #Assign the return value to a variable
     isValidIp=$?
   else
      isValidIp=1
  fi

  if [ $isValidIp -eq "0" ]
    then
       numberOfIps=$(( $numberOfIps + 1 ))
       echo "$numberOfIps) $serverIp --> is valid"     

       if [ "$sysType" = "ebox" ]
       then
               echo "$serverIp is an eBox device.."
           echo "About to pass $serverIp as argument to connct.sh"
           #./connct.sh $serverIp
           ssh "$address" ARG1=$rpmFileName 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'
        echo ">>Checksum ..."
           ENDSSH
        fi
    else
       echo "$serverIp --> is invalid"
    fi    
    echo ""
done < $file
```

Comment: Can you post the code that didn't work, so we can help you debug it?

Comment: And put it in a code block (by indenting four spaces) so that it's easier to read.

Comment: Did you add spaces before `ENDSSH`? Can you show the while loop?

Comment: Here's a guess: If your "loop" is something like a while-loop that reads IP addresses from a file, then you have a conflict: both the `read` and `ssh` commands want to consume stdin. But as @Adam says, we'll need to see the code.

Comment: @glennjackman - in that case your loop will just run once (since ssh will eat the rest your stdin), not throw a syntax error.

Comment: The ssh won't consume stdin because the here-document provides the stdin for that command.

Comment: not sure how to paste code in reply

Comment: Friends updated the original post with the code, as i'm not able to paste entire code in reply to thread. Please go through the code and let me know your suggestions..... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the '-n' ssh switch

e.g.:

```
for i in {1..7}
do
    ssh -n myhost$i mycommand
done
```